# How to express percentage in Cocos2d - ObjC

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to use relative coordinates with a game I'm making in Cocos2D so that the title sits in the middle of the screen on the iPhone 5 (since its a bit longer) and in the middle of the iPhone 3-4 (since they're the same)

How can I express size.width/2, and size.height/2 in a percentage so that it sits properly in both devices?

```
//Label Position 
label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
```

Thanks! :3

Comment: 1/2 = 0.5, size.width /2 = size.width*0.5f, this is what you need?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to set it in the middle but I've tried those numbers and it doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Try this

```
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    sprite.position = ccp(size.width*0.5f, size.height*0.5f);
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! That did it. I forgot about floats (its late) :p

Answer (score 1):

```
 If you wanna your app support iphone5,dont forget add a 4-inch launchimage.
```

otherwise,you cant get correct scrSize with [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].